# clearing / resetting the selenium webdriver between junit tests

Tags: junit4, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian

I am using arquillian graphene with selenium webdriver and I have an irritating problem.

The WebDriver seems to retain page state in between each test. I am currently testing a login page and the first test checks for a login failure. This works.

The second test checks for login success. When run on its own, it works fine. However, run together with the one above, it fails. In looking at the page output, it seems that the username field is a combination of the username from the first test and the second test.

For example, the first test sets the username to "non-existent" and the second test sets the username to "test" and this works if I run the tests individually.

If I run them together, the username fields ends up with "non-existenttest"

This suggests that the webdriver does not "reset" / "clear" the page in between tests.

Is there some way to get it to reset it?

I have currently worked around the issue by calling the clear() method on each of the fields @Before test.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Reloading the application url in the @Before method ?

Comment: I assume you mean the .navigation().refresh() method. I have tried this with no success.

Comment: Say, if the application url is http://example.com then try loading exactly the same within @Before. In case this also does not work, then I feel it is a defect in the application, unless it is designed that way for some reason.

Comment: that pointed me in the right direction. I am not sure why I didn't think of it before but I just deleted all the cookies @ After the test. This meant that we had a starting point closer to how it would be if each test was the first one run. Thank you.